# Count number of time stamps that are in a certain day

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have several years of timestamps, each of 10 minutes in duration. See below example:

```
TIMESTAMP
03/04/2009 14:40
03/04/2009 14:50
03/04/2009 15:00
...
01/12/2013 00:10
```

I want to obtain a count of all timestamps that have the day 03/04/2010. I am trying to achieve this using countif, with round applied to the range as an array formula as below:

```
COUNTIF(ROUND(F19:F22,0),"=I17")
```

entered as ctrl+shift+enter, where "I17" is a cell containing the date 03/04/2010 and F19:F22 is the range of timestamps.

My timestamps are formatted as custom format of the style dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

What is the error in my formula or my approach?

Comment: How is the time stamp data formatted? Is it text or custom date/time?

Comment: Is/was the source a CSV/TXT file or is/was it an Excel file?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't answer our questions. The format of the data is important to helping you get this working.

Comment: question now edited to describe format.